# Converting Android Numberpicker Maven Project to Gradle Project For Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio, numberpicker

So I've started using Android Studio and I wanted to use a number picker library for my project. Specifically this one:

https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker

This is a maven project and my project is gradle based. In order to use this project in my app I would need to convert it into a gradle library project. Easy! Or so I thought...

I used the following articles for guidance:

http://www.androidsx.com/how-to-link-an-android-library-project-with-gradle-in-android-studio/
http://ryanharter.com/blog/2013/07/17/migrating-android-projects-to-gradle/

My directory structure is as follows:

```
android-numberpicker/
   - android-numberpicker/
      - src/
         - main/
            - res/
            - java/
      - build.gradle
   - settings.gradle
   - build.gradle
```

My settings.gradle file

```
include ':android-numberpicker'
```

My build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-reporting'

/**
 * Task to generate a gradle wrapper.
 */
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.9'
}
```

and my android-numberpicker/build.gradle file looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 15
    }
}
```

Now I haven't even tried to integrate it with my project or android studio. I just want to see if I could build the project on its own. In other words i wanted to see if i had ported the project to gradle correctly. However when I run ./gradlew build (I am using the gradle wrapper) I get a series of errors such as:

```
NumberPicker.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProvider;
                                 ^
```

No idea why gradle is doing this?

I did notice in the original projects pom file the following dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Which I originally disregarded because I would have thought the 'android-library' plugin would automatically resolve the android sdk. However, when I got the above error I decided to add it to my android-numberpicker/build.gradle as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.google.android:android:+"
}
```

I used compile, since the android-library doesn't seem to recognize provided as a valid scope. Upon running ./gradlew build I got a different error:

> ERROR: Debug has an indirect dependency on Android API level 15, but minSdkVersion for variant 'debug' is API level 7

Again, not really sure why I am getting this error. Have reached a brick wall with regards to this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make these all correction mentioned below and sync your project with gradle.

1) Remove this dependency from your build.gradle file

```
compile "com.google.android:android:+"
```

2) Remove this from **android-numberpicker/build.gradle** after applying android plugin

```
 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }
```

No use of it, you already defined in root gradle file.

3) Change you **minSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion** in android-numberpicker/build.gradle to **16** because class has been add in API Level 16

Check this fro reference
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeProvider.html

Sync your project with gradle after all these changes and let me know if you face any issue.

**EDIT :**

I found this in NumberPicker Library code :

```
class SupportAccessibilityNodeProvider {

        AccessibilityNodeProviderImpl mProvider;

        private SupportAccessibilityNodeProvider() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                mProvider = new AccessibilityNodeProviderImpl();
            }
        }

        public boolean performAction(int virtualViewId, int action, Bundle arguments) {
            if (mProvider != null) {
                return mProvider.performAction(virtualViewId, action, arguments);
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void sendAccessibilityEventForVirtualView(int virtualViewId, int eventType) {
            if (mProvider != null) mProvider.sendAccessibilityEventForVirtualView(virtualViewId, eventType);
        }
    }
```

Which shows library handles it for lower versions so you can make your compileSDKVersion as 16 and minSdkVersion as 7/8.

Also have to add support v4 library in your project using this in dependency iside build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
```

Comment: I saw this and it confused me. Because if you look at the AndroidManifest.xml in the original project it says minSdkVersion="7", targetSdkVersion="15". Also one of the reasons i chose this project was because it is supposed to be compatible with API version 7. Using API version 16 defeats the point of using this library and Android's own number picker is compatible with versions 11 upwards. What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure but can you try just to make compileSdkVersion 16 and minSdkVersion as 8. It might be possible that library handled the API levels inside code and acts accordingly.

Comment: I was correct the library handled that, check my edit if it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It compiles, but lint doesn't like it so i had to disable it. Its confusing that the AndroidManifest would specify a minSdkVersion version of 7 and a compileSdkVersion of 15 if the project cannot support it. Any reason why it would do this?

Comment: manifest doesn't specify the compileSdkVersion. It can only have min, max and target. "15" is the target in library that doesn't mean that it has been compiled by author using API level 15.BTW using gradle will replace the details mentioned in manifest by values in build.gradle for these all. Let me know if everything is working fine or not ?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation pyus13. That worked and I've successfully managed to use it in my project.

Comment: Wow great, Cheers! happy to help you. Enjoy your Studio journey.

Comment: Hi sorry to mess with an old thread , can U update what solution worked .. Would really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the `AccessibilityNodeProvider` [JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeProvider.html), that class was added in API 16, but you've set a minSdkVersion of 7 in your build file.